# How do you get the link for a media item?

Tags: media-library, link-manager

I have an item in the media library in Sitecore and I want to place a link to that item on the site. How do I properly get the link for that media item?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will also fold in protection for the media request:

```cs
var theURL = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(theURL);
```

Here is the link to Sitecore documentation that explains about protecting Sitecore media from abuse - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/protect_media_request

Comment: link is broken, 2019-02-27

Answer (score 18):

Getting the URL of a `MediaItem` is pretty straightforward, you pass the `MediaItem` reference to `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl`:

```cs
var url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
```

`GetMediaUrl` takes an optional second parameter of `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions`, which can be used to add query string parameters to the URL which are useful for a number of dynamic image generation features.

Some of the settings that can be changed are:

- height
- width
- max height
- max width
- background color
- aspect ratio mode
- scale

```cs
var options = new MediaUrlOptions { Width = 400, Height = 300 };
var resizedUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, options);
```

---

If you're using Sitecore 8 or newer, Sitecore has a built-in check to prevent malicious users from requesting lots of image resizing on the server and DDOSing your site.

To make use of this new utility, pass the url returned from `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl` to `Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl`:

```cs
var options = new MediaUrlOptions { ... };
var unsafeUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, options);
var url = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(unsafeUrl);
```

---

Lastly, Sitecore's url generation will often include spaces that aren't properly percent encoded. This will cause issues in particular situations, such as assigning a Sitecore url to the `[content]` attribute of `<meta property="og:image" content="..." />`.

I haven't seen issues with other characters, so the simplest solution I've found is to just use `String.Replace`:

```cs
var url =
    MediaManager
        .GetMediaUrl(mediaItem /*, options */)
        .Replace(" ", "%20");
```

<sub>Sitecore does have a large number of encoding bugs, so I wouldn't be surprised if other special characters were found that also needed to be percent encoded.</sub>

---

For convenience, I use an extension method for getting `MediaItem` urls:

```cs
public static class MediaItemExtensions
{
  public static string GetUrl(this MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options = null)
  {
    if (item == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

    if (options == null)
      options = new MediaUrlOptions();

    var url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

#if SITECORE8
    url = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url);
#endif

    url = url.Replace(" ", "%20");

    return url;
  }
}
```

which can be used as:

```cs
var url = mediaItem.GetUrl(/* options */);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField myImageItem = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["MyImageField"];
```

then:

```cs
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(myImageItem.MediaItem);
```

Answer (score 4):

MediaManager has a GetMediaUrl method that can be used for this:

```cs
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item);
```

Sample usage:

```cs
string mediaUrl = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix( '/',
  Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem));
```

Comment: A complete answer should include GetAssertUrlHash() these days. Ref: http://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.ch/2015/06/media-hash-and-resizing.html