# Replacing Text in strings from SPE Invoke-RemoteScript Return adds many spaces

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am getting an item from Sitecore, then taking the return and messing with the FullName to build the URL.

```
Import-Module -Name SPE

        $Id = [Some Id]

        $session = New-ScriptSession -Username [un]-Password [pw] -ConnectionUri http://sitecorehostname
        $Item = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                $item = Get-Item -Path "master:/media library" -Id "$($params.id)"
                $item | Get-Member
                $item
        } -Arguments @{"id"=$Id}
        Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session

        $Url = $Item.FullPath
        $Url = $Url -replace "^/sitecore/shell/sitecore/", "/-/"
        $Url = $Url -replace "^/sitecore/", "/-/"
        $Url = $Url -replace "^/media library/", "/media/"
        $tempKey = $Item.Key + "/"
        $Url = $Url -replace $tempKey, $Item.Key
        $Url = "http://sitecorehostname" + $Url
```

At the end of this code, the value of $Url is "http//sitecorehostname[About 1000 spaces]+[$Item.FullPath with replaced strings]

What confuses me is if I take the text of $Item.FullPath and just run some test code below:

```
$Url = "/sitecore/media library/Images/ThatOneImage"
$Url = $Url -Replace "^/sitecore/shell/sitecore/", "/-/"
$Url = $Url -Replace "^/sitecore/", "/-/"
$Url = $Url -Replace "^/media library/", "/media/"
etc...
```

I get a proper URL without all the extra spaces. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first change I can see here that I would make is to not return the entire item. SPE serializes the entire item and re-hydrates on the other end. From your example you only need the `FullPath`.

Import-Module -Name SPE

```
$Id = "{6AA5AA9F-071A-4808-91AC-709FAAFFB310}"

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username "admin" -Password "b" -ConnectionUri https://remotesitecore
$Url = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $item = Get-Item -Path "master:/media library" -Id "$($params.id)"
    $item.FullPath
} -Arguments @{"id"=$Id}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session

$Url = $Url -replace "/sitecore/shell/sitecore/", "/-/"
$Url = $Url -replace "/sitecore/", "/-/"
$Url = $Url -replace "/media library/", "/media/"
$tempKey = $Item.Key + "/"
$Url = $Url -replace $tempKey, $Item.Key
$Url = "http://sitecorehostname" + $Url
```

When I run it I don't get the trailing spaces. You can however simply call `Trim` on the string and it'll take care of it.

#### Update

You can also change the script to return a specific set of properties. You'll essentially get a skinny object back.

```powershell
$item | Select-Object -Property Name, ID, FullPath
```

Comment: I needed more data, so I ended up passing back an array of properties. But this is a correct answer, so I will select it as the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover a scenario where you need more properties.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the Media Item Path and building up the URl yourself, you should instead use the `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()` method to return the URL. If you are string parsing from Item Path then it also will not include the file extension.

```
$site = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory]::GetSiteContext("website")
$mediaItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Id "{6AA5AA9F-071A-4808-91AC-709FAAFFB310}"

$Url = New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher $site) {
    [Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager]::GetMediaUrl($mediaItem)
}

$Url = "http://sitecorehostname" + $Url
```

This ensures that any custom Link Provider that may be implemented is also used.

Note: If your `Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` setting is `true` then you will need to call the overloaded `GetMediaUrl` method and pass in `MediaUrlOptions` and set the value to false (else strip out the current server URL).

Comment: Be good if this also included request protection. As seen here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/how-do-you-get-the-link-for-a-media-item/1243#1243

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Request protection is only required if parameters are being manipulated, e.g. height/width. **Just** to request the default image size it makes no difference. I can update the example to show this (but also reluctant since issue the OP had was related to the remote call itself). Let me know and I'll update if you think it will be useful.

Comment: My bad. Misread documentation; thought we were meant to always protect media Urls these days :-)